# How do I fix corrupted NTFS in ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have an external NTFS drive that is not able to mount.

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda File/
```

This gives me

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I tried `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda`

And it gives me

```
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

In order to run  chkdsk, I have to access Windows. However, I currently cannot.

Since this drive is new and has nothing inside, I do not afraid losing data.
Are there any solutions to fix this in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you are sure that your external disk is /dev/sda (check with `dmesg` in terminal just after plugging the disk in), you probably have to mount the partition on the disk, that is `/dev/sda1)`.

Comment: Use `testdisk` for Linux. First run for analysis and second run for repair if it makes sense.

Comment: I suggest following Rizwind's answer and just format it again with GParted. Additionally I would suggest creating a new partition table (GPT) from the start. Use menu Device > New partition table.

Comment: It happened to me after I've unsafely removed my USB external drive. Only re-formatting with `gparted` helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ntfsfix`.

```
sudo ntfsfix dev/sda1
```

and I think you should give the partition number in your mount command,
`dev/sda` is the disk and `dev/sda1` is normally the first partition.

Comment: I just mounted sda1 (the first partition) successfully, but the first partition is only 524MB big, Disks shows that the actual 3GB is from the unallocated dev/sda. I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @user963700 try using `gparted`. 
`sudo apt install gparted`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally fixing a problem in a specific operating system needs to be fixed from tools that come from that operating system.  Mind though that the system claims it is NOT a NTFS volume so NTFS tools will not work.

Mind the following questions:

- Could it be another filesystem?
- Are you sure you have the ntfs-tools istalled? Otherwise NTFS is an unknown filesystem.
- It should be `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 File/`

> Since this drive is new and has nothing inside, I do not afraid losing data. Are there any solutions to fix this in Ubuntu?

That is maybe 1 exception to the statement above.  You can use Gparted to format the disk (using NTFS as filesystem). That will circumvent current problems with the filesystem on a disk. But be sure your check the questions 1st.

Mind that your problem could be an actual hardware problem and this will not fix actual hardware errors. If Gparted crashes out of the operation that disk is probably broken beyond repair.